# C# how to design html in a xaml page

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml, toolbox

So I want to make a htmlpage in a xaml-window. I searched the net, but the only thing I found was how to edit the text, but not how it is shown in the page. I want to create (or use, if it already exists) a toolbox for html. and i want to put this in a xaml-window so I can edit the output of a piece of html code. In the toolbox may be for example: inputfield,image, table

anyone who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, if you want to render a HTML page in WPF application, you can use WPF [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) Control.

Answer (score 0):

First of all be specific weather you are working on wpf or silverlight... I don't know much about wpf, but for silverlight try this..  http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/13910/157537.aspx